# How can MyWebsite ship a javascript package jQuery or AngularJS, that websiteA and websiteB can use, without conflicts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cross-domain

Say I have a website, MyWebsite, where you can build content for a call-to-action-box that should show on another website, WebsiteA, and on more websites that choose our solution *without using an iframe*.

How can that *box* be created using jQuery or AngularJS, without conflicts, without knowing what the customer has in their webpage, **they just import our some_script.js** set some settings and that's it. Most importantly, we can't mess up the customers side (obviously), nor should whatever tech the customer is using, mess up our superduper box.

I would love to see a *working example*. This is hard (I think), so please take more time to think before answering if you haven't solved such a problem. Appreciate the help guys!

Comment: have a look at require.js

Comment: One idea is to embeded both `jQuery` and `AngularJS` inside your `scome_script.js`, and make use of `.noConflict()`.

Comment: @runTam, how does that work if the client app already has jQuery, in a different version than yours? can you prove this idea through a working example :)

Comment: @Donal please elaborate, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [web storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) HTML5 and javascript, web pages can store data locally within the user's browser.

Comment: Webcomponents, check out polymer-project. The idea is that all the functionality and dependencies of the box would be packaged and sandboxed to just your box.

Comment: why do you need a beast like jQuery or Angular to show some content? can't you export a more basic vanilla version that doesn't need a ton of external code? i don't even care _if_ you somehow manage to keep it from breaking my site, it will still slow down my pageload a lot.

Comment: guys, appreciate the enthusiasm, but the question isn't to jQuery or not to jQuery, or to/not to use AngularJS. If you wanna use polymer, your choice for your problem :) dandavis, you don't have to load on page load. You may load later, cache and use it blazingly fast. There are too many clever ways to do things, right now I'm concerned about not screwing up Client X env in neither scoping, loading, crippling way. This Q touches on the scope problem :)

Comment: @oma, Hope you see the updated answer with working demos http://stackoverflow.com/a/25492332/880434

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**RequireJS allows you to create consumable JQuery / AngularJS Apps (AMDs) without worrying about version conflicts**

Rather than worrying about library `noconflict's`, ***RequireJS*** creates a separate sandbox / variable scope outside the global with an ***AMD***. Within ***AMD***, only included versions are available.

***AMD*** -  **[Asynchronous Module Definitions](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD)**  are self-enclosed applications with their own scope for libraries. Self-Encolsure is like namespacing, complete no-conflict. Refer to **[WHY WEB MODULES](http://requirejs.org/docs/why.html)** for a detailed explanation for using modules.

An ***AngularJS*** example, create an `AngularMain.js` file:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",    
    paths: {
       'angular': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min',
       'angularAMD': 'lib/angularAMD.min',
       'ngload': 'lib/ngload.min'
    },
    shim: { 'angularAMD': ['angular'], 'angular-route': ['angular'] },
    deps: ['AngularApp']
});
```

Now, `require.config` has indicated that ***AngularApp.js*** should also be included (as you'll see, RequireJS usually assumes ".js" extensions), with dependancies on ***angular.js*** and ***angular-route.js***

You now define your Angular App and Controllers using a combination of ***RequireJS*** and ***AngularJS*** syntax in your `AngularApp.js` file:

```
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route'], function (angularAMD) {
    var app = angular.module("webapp", ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/home", angularAMD.route({
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            controllerUrl: 'ctrl/home'
        }))
    });
    return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
});

define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Message from HomeCtrl"; 
    });
});
```

**Finally:** your HTML page requests references you app with a reference to require.js and a `data-main` attribute indicating app file.

```
<script data-main="js/AngularMain" src=".../require.js"></script>
```

**Once again:** the ".js" file extension is optional

---

- much of this code example borrowed from ***[marcoslin.github.io](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD)***
- tnajdek has an ***[angular-requirejs-seed](https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed)*** Git Hub repo for building angular apps with require pre-configured.
- **[RequireJS Official Site](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)** has a good tutorial on creating a ***JQuery*** ***AMD***.

Comment: And what if someone overwrites the `define` function? ;)

Comment: @GuyT, please explain what you mean... The `define` function is part of the **Require** library referenced in the call `<script data-main="js/AngularMain" src=".../require.js"></script>` Are you suggesting that somebody will tamper with **Require** Library???

Comment: @GuyT, the more I think about it, the less I understand **What you mean**

Comment: @DaveA - I think another way to reword GuyT's question is, what if the website is already using a dependency loader with  a different footprint for `define`, or a different version of requirejs, or another script which loads later and overwrites `define`?

Comment: @RyanWheale, great question! If you study the syntax  `<script data-main="js/AngularMain" src=".../require.js">`, you will notice there is reference to a specific library of **RequireJS** AND a MainAppDefinition. This combination is a specific App (AMD) with it's own scope built on this specific version of **RequireJS** and this App Definition. Multiple Apps (AMD's) built on different versions of **RequireJS** and Loading different versions of JS libs can exist within the same web page. This is exactly the advantage of AMD Applications over Global Libs or no-conflicts.

Comment: In fact, the AMD exists regardless of what happens in the Global scope or any other loader scope (even another App built on this same loader (as long as its a different instance). And the Global scope can have it's own loader or redefinition of `define` function. Will have no impact on this App.

Comment: I'm new to RequireJS. I've spent a lot of time wrapping my head around this, but I've had other deadlines this week and haven't yet "proved" this approach. I think this is the most promising approach though and awarding the bounty here. I won't mark as accepted until I've implemented it and it proves to really work:) I'm grateful for the attention I got for my Q, it shows that SO truly rocks. You guys rock!

Comment: @oma,Thanks for the bounty! if you have any further Q's about implementation, post comments here and in your OP Q.

Comment: @DaveA Ryan Wheale's explanation is correct. That was exactly what I meant and I wasn't aware of the `RequireJS` approach. Thank you for that. ps. I'm sorry that I answer after 2 weeks, but I was on holiday :)

Answer (score 4):

You can check whether jQuery is loaded correctly by following code,

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined'){
    // jQuery related code
}
```

You can detect whether angular is loaded correctly by using following code,

```
if(typeof angular != 'undefined') {
    // angular related code
}
```

So there wont be any conflicts in the code, if jQuery is there, jQuery code will run. And if Angular is there, Angular code will run.

You can use jQuery noconflict to ensure that `$` wont conflict with any other library

```
(function($){
   // jQuery code here will not conflict with any other codes.
 })(jQuery);
```

If you have multiple versions of angular, following code will help you to solve the conflicts. [More Details](http://www.mattburkedev.com/multiple-angular-versions-on-the-same-page/)

```
(function() {
  // Save a copy of the existing angular for later restoration
  var existingWindowDotAngular = window.angular;

  // create a new window.angular and a closure variable for 
  // angular.js to load itself into
  var angular = (window.angular = {});

  /*
   * Copy-paste angular.js and modules here. They will load themselves into
   * the window.angular object we just created (which is also aliased as
   * "angular")
   */

  ..

  // notice this refers to the local angular variable declared above, not
  // window.angular
  angular.module('MyWidget', ['ngSanitize']);

  ...

  //Manually bootstrap so the old angular version doesn't encounter
  //ng-app='MyWidget' and blow up
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('my-widget', ['MyWidget']);

    // restore the old angular version
    window.angular = existingWindowDotAngular;
  });
});
```

Comment: "if jQuery is there, jQuery code will run. And if Angular is there, Angular code will run.". What version of jQuery? or Angular? What if I need a newer one, or older? :)

Comment: `jQuery.fn.jquery` will return the version of the jQuery and `angular.version` will return the angular version

Comment: You are missing the point @ChamikaSandamal . He wants to include a script in his own function, but as far as I know is that impossible due to CORS.

Comment: see my new answer with working examples http://stackoverflow.com/a/25492332/880434

Comment: @GuyT " He wants to include a script in his own function". Where do you get that from? I build the script, YOU use it in your app. You expect it to just work, not screwing up your env. if you use angular, you don't want me to change it, that's why I don't see how changing ´window.angular' wouldn't screw it up Chamika

Comment: @oma, If you read my other answer with Demos you will see how to do it without screw user's site. we load the angular or  jquery inside our code if it is not match with our requirement. and do our work and then again reset the angular or jquery to the default version. you can see the demo. it is working perfectly as you expected

Answer (score 4):

You can use following function to add custom script to the page,

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

and for the jQuery code you can try the following code

```
var myCode = function () {
    var jQuery_your_version = $.noConflict(true);
    (function ($) {
        // your custom code will go inside this section
        $("#output").append("New code with version: " + $.fn.jquery + "<br/>");
    }(jQuery_your_version));

    $("#output").append("New code with version: " + $.fn.jquery + "<br/>");
};

if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined' || $.fn.jquery != "1.11.1") {
    loadScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js", myCode);
} else {
    myCode();
}

$("#output").append("Old code with version: " + $.fn.jquery + "<br/>");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vu725336/)

For the angular code,

```
var myCode = function (ang, oldAngular) {
    $("#output").append("New custom code with version: " + ang.version.full + "<br/>");
    window.angular = angular = oldAngular;

    // this is after your code and it is refering to the old angular
    $("#output").append("New code with version: " + angular.version.full + "<br/>");
};

if (typeof angular == 'undefined' || angular.version.full != "1.2.20") {
    var existingWindowDotAngular = window.angular;
    var angular = (window.angular = {});
    loadScript("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js", function () {
        myCode(angular, existingWindowDotAngular);
    });
} else {
    myCode(angular, angular);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/co6ym3pz/)

**EDIT**

Some more details about angular code for better understanding,

`var existingWindowDotAngular = window.angular;` will load the existing `angular` object to a variable
then `var angular = (window.angular = {});` will reset the existing `angular` object.

next code `loadScript()` will load the required angular version and it will create new angular object with new version. then in the callback function, we can do the work you need. 
so if you see the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/co6ym3pz/), you will see it will display the new version
then we reset the `window.angular` to old version using `window.angular = angular = oldAngular;`
so in the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/co6ym3pz/), now it will display the old version.

Comment: I don't see how this wouldn't screw up the Customer app if he already uses angular version X and you using version Y in your script he imports. window.angular is a global var.

Comment: @oma, updated the answer for better understanding. let me know if it is still not clear

Answer (score 2):

### Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)

> A common pattern in JavaScript is the immediately-invoked function
>   expression. This pattern creates a function expression and then
>   immediately executes the function. This pattern is extremely useful
>   for cases where you want to avoid polluting the global namespace with
>   code – no variables declared inside of the function are visible
>   outside of it.

Source: http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/#immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife

### Protecting the $ Alias and Adding Scope

> The $ variable is very popular among JavaScript libraries, and if
>   you're using another library with jQuery, you will have to make jQuery
>   not use the $ with jQuery.noConflict(). However, this will break our
>   plugin since it is written with the assumption that $ is an alias to
>   the jQuery function. To work well with other plugins, and still use
>   the jQuery $ alias, we need to put all of our code inside of an
>   Immediately Invoked Function Expression, and then pass the function
>   jQuery, and name the parameter $:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.greenify = function() {
        this.css( "color", "green" );
        return this;
    };

    $.ltrim = function( str ) {
        return str.replace( /^\s+/, "" );
    };

    $.rtrim = function( str ) {
        return str.replace( /\s+$/, "" );
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

source: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

When you look at the IIFE structure you will see something like:

```
(function($){})( jQuery ));
```

The `jQuery` variable is the global object that you are passing to the function so the `$` sign will be always a 'clean' jQuery variable in the rest of your function. If I was you I would learn this pattern and use it in all your JavaScript to avoid conflicts. Ofcourse, the site that is using your script(s) have to include `jQuery`(or anyother library you want to use).

To show you how it works I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/2748y083/1/).

---

### Update

I get your point. You want to include your library by yourself so you will never have conflicts. When something sounds to good to be true it usually is. You are not the first one who wants this. The 'problem' is called `CORS`. You can't include something from another (sub)domain without permission(could be set server side). This is really a security issue. I did my best to show you this in my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2748y083/2/).

Comment: same comment as others: "The jQuery variable is the global object" - that's a problem too.

Comment: How do **IIFE** control for version scoping?

Comment: @DaveA It doesn't, but at least you are defining your own scope.

Answer (score 1):

With the given libraries `noConflict()` function it is easy to restore everything, after usage.

The jquery part is easy already:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

When you run this:

```
jQuery.noConflict( true );
```

Jquery cleans everything from the global name space.

The angular situation is less clear. There is a related pull request:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8596

Which means you have to wait them to merge this to stable, or you have to do this manually.
Anyway this will restore the pre-angular state:

```
angular.noConflict();
```

If you want to create one big file, it should be something similar:

1. Insert the jquery source. or
2. Insert the angular.js source (with the PR applied)
3. Do whatever you like with them.
4. And restore the original state with these 2 lines:

Code:

```
jQuery.noConflict( true );
angular.noConflict();
```

Comment: even if angular enables noConflicts, you can't assume the that client is on that version. He might be on an old and `angular`, having that in the global namespace, causing your app to crash.

Comment: The noconflict calls reset the global namespace to the state before the related library was loaded. So if there was an other library before loading "the script" then the noConflict resets it, but you can use the library you loaded in the script. Basically you can load anything use it, and at the end reset the globals to the original state.

Answer (score 1):

The approach described below should run at any web page where javascript is enabled. Library agnostic. No dependencies. Utilizing a `jsonp` type approach.

Create a `form` element to customize "Call-To-Action" settings. Save the selected / created settings to a `json` object - or, create un-saved on-the-fly. Including global identifier for the specific client and your own database.

Incorporate the saved settings into a `IIFE` , called by script at client page , resulting in a `jsonp` call.

i.e.g.,

After collecting settings at a `form` , saving to a `json` object , completed `iife` at server / service could appear as

```
(function() {
  var button = document.createElement("button"); // jsonObj.outerElem
  var link = document.createElement("a"); // jsonObj.innerElem
  link.href = "#"; // jsonObj.href  
  link.innerText = "Call To Action!"; //  jsonObj.label
  link.style.textDecoration = "none"; // jsonObj.styles
  button.appendChild(link);  // order jsonObj elems for DOM display
  button.style.fontSize = "36px"; // jsonObj.styles
  return callback(button) // return jsonObj elems
}());
```

the above file name would include the global identifier for the settings saved at the `json` object for that client , e.g., "cta-123.js" , where **123** would be the global `[client-id]` for the client and/or the client's customized `json` object and/or callback function.

At the client side , *2* `script` tags , in the below order

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// define global `callback` function
// `cta` : `Call-To-Action` `button`, `form` , `element` , etc.
callback = function(cta) {
  // do stuff with `cta`
  document.body.appendChild(cta)
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cta-service/cta-[client-id].js">
```

Resulting in the "Call-To-Action" element being appended to element defined by client at `callback`

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/rgokqyfp/

Answer (score 1):

"Namespace" your code in a closure and only include any libraries if they don't already exist in the page. The best way to do that would be as such..

### some_script.js

```
(function(root) {

    function includeJQuery() {
        var s = root.document.createElement('script');
        s.src = "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js";
        root.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    }

    function waitForJQuery() {
        if(root.jQuery === undefined || root.jQuery.fn.jquery !== "1.11.1") {
            root.setTimeout(waitForJQuery, 100);
        } else {
            var jQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
            initMyApplication(jQ);
        }        
    }

    if(root.jQuery === undefined || root.jQuery.fn.jquery !== "1.11.1") {
        includeJQuery();
        waitForJQuery();
    } else {
        initMyApplication(root.jQuery);
    }

    function initMyApplication(jQuery) {
        //
        // YOUR CODE HERE
        //
    }

}(window));
```

Remember to change any occurrences of `window` in your code to `root` and any functions that you want to be accessed globally will need to be properties of `root`.

For example: if you wanted the function `createCtaModal()` to be called by the user, you would define it in code as:

```
root.createCtaModal = function() {
    ...
}
```

### EDIT

An edit has been made so you can use a specific version of jQuery...

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2rg7cq26/2/

Comment: You lack check of the loaded jQuery version. What if it is earlier/later version than the one the OP needs?

Comment: Fair question, however this was not stated in the question as a required feature. All OP wanted was a way that required the customer to reference one javascript library, and have it not interfere with the existing customer code.

Comment: For the sake of version checking not being a bad idea, I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

1. Using JSONP to load your version of jQuery (See http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html)
2. Using IIFE as follows

   (function ( $  ) {
   /* your JQUERY code goes here */
   }) (jQuery.noConflict(true));

We are utilizing the fact that http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ returns reference to the JQuery function.